# How to know which side is talking during phone call in android

Tags: android, audio-recording, analyzer, phone-call

I would like to know , in real time but that other problem , which side is talking , i thinking about record the call and do some audio analyze after but it seem to me very complex and overkill that might not work as expected...

any ideas ?

Comment: You can monitor small speaker and microphone : if speaker in use mean that user hearing if microphone word mean user talking.

Comment: with what do i monitor ? i have tried with UP and DOWN LINK , now i am reading and testing the Visualizer class